# Multi-level maps with a list over template in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have a requirement to generate around ten YAML files and use `kubernetes_manifest` resource to apply them. Most of the content in the YAML is constant, only a few parameters change. Some YAML files have a repetitive ports section, in the below example I have `http` and `https` under the ports section. In some cases, I have three `http`, `https` and `sql`. Based on the inputs I should be able to generate a yaml file out of the template file. The below code works fine when I have only one section under ports like only `http`. I have confusion as to how to loop the ports section. should i create a map of map?
I am using Terraform v1.2.2. I request you to help me correct my issue or suggest an alternate idea/solution achieve my goal

**Expected File after generation**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - 'api.facebook.com'
  ports:
  - name: http
    number: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: NONE
```

**Template file**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: ${service_entry}
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  hosts:
  - ${jsonencode(hosts)}
  ports:
  %{ for name, number, protocol in service_entry ~}
  - name: ${name}
    number: ${number}
    protocol: ${protocol}
  %{ endfor ~}
  resolution: ${resolution}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "service-entry" {
  for_each = var.service_entry
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/service_entry.yaml.tpl", {
    service_entry_name = each.value.service_entry
    namespace          = each.value.namespace
    hosts              = each.value.hosts
    name               = each.value.name
    number             = each.value.number
    protocol           = each.value.protocol
    resolution         = each.value.resolution
  }))
}
```

**varibles.tf**

```
variable "service_entry" {
  type = map(object({
    service_entry = string
    namespace     = string
    hosts         = string
    name          = list(string)
    number        = list(string)
    protocol      = list(string)
    resolution    = string
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

**tfvars**
Below tfvars should generate two yaml files. the first YAML would have two sections under ports `http` `https` and the second YAML would have three sections under ports `http` `https` and `sql`

```
service_entry = {
  app1 = {
    service_entry = "test"
    namespace     = "test"
    hosts         = "api.facebook.com"
    resolution    = "NONE"
    name          = ["http", "https"]
    number        = ["8080", "443"] 
    protocol      = ["TCP", "TCP"]
 },
  app2 = {
    service_entry = "example"
    namespace     = "example"
    hosts         = "api.facebook.com"
    resolution    = "NONE"
    name          = ["http", "https", "sql"]
    number        = ["8080", "443", "5432"] 
    protocol      = ["TCP","TCP","TCP"]
    }
}
```

**Current error**

```
 Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ../../modules/service_entry/main.tf line 3, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "service-entry":
│    3:   manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/service_entry.yaml.tpl", {
│    4:     service_entry_name = each.value.service_entry_name
│    5:     namespace          = each.value.namespace
│    6:     hosts              = each.value.hosts
│    7:     name               = each.value.name
│    8:     number             = each.value.number
│    9:     protocol           = each.value.protocol
│   10:     resolution         = each.value.resolution
│   11:   }))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.hosts will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.namespace will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.name will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.number will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.protocol will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.resolution will be known only after apply
│     │ each.value.service_entry_name will be known only after apply
│     │ path.module is "../../modules/service_entry"
│
│ Call to function "templatefile" failed:
│ ../../modules/service_entry/templates/service_entry.yaml.tpl:11,32-33:
│ Invalid 'for' directive; For directive requires 'in' keyword after names.,
│ and 1 other diagnostic(s).
╵
ERRO[0005] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

Comment: You have to explain what's wrong with the current code? What is current output? What is expected output?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my question. My current code works fine with having only one section under ports. I am not sure how to update the template to accommodate multiple sections under the port.

Comment: What is the actual or example value of `var.service_entry` that you use to obtain your current and expected results?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the current and expected tfvars. Apologize I will include all these in the first attempt

Comment: Your `Expected tfvars` is incorrect. It does not conform to your `type` of `service_entry`. So there is no way this code will even run. Sadly your question is not clear nor reproducible.

Comment: @Marcin My `type` `service_entry`  doesn't match the expected tfvars because I am not sure how to build the type for my expected tfvars and that's the help I am asking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246184/discussion-between-eva-and-marcin).

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the error. If possible Please check now, and if possible please let me know my mistake

Comment: Sorry, couldn't join the chat, but I provided the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to work with templates, in your case yaml, is to wrap everything in `yamlencode`. So your `service_entry.yaml.tpl` can be:

```
${yamlencode(
{
    apiVersion = "networking.istio.io/v1beta1"
    kind = "ServiceEntry"
    metadata = {
      name = service_entry_name
      namespace = namespace    
    }  
    spec = {
      "hosts" = [hosts]
      ports = [ for idx in range(length(name)):
            {
               name: name[idx]
               number: number[idx]
               protocol: protocol[idx]            
            }
      ]
    }    
}
)}
```

This generates valid `yaml` file and you don't have to fight against the strange templating syntax.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, really helped with an issue I was resolving. Here is an example of my usage of your code. In the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of the accepted answer by @Marcin, here is example usage. NOTE: You need to create seperate service entries for services with hosts that don't use/expose the same ports. E.g. hosts that don't support HTTPS/TLS cannot be in the same service entry as hosts that do.

```
// ./modules/istio/manifests/serviceEntry.yaml.tpl
${yamlencode(
{
    apiVersion = "networking.istio.io/v1beta1"
    kind = "ServiceEntry"
    metadata = {
      name = service_entry_name
      namespace = namespace    
    }  
    spec = {
      "hosts" = [hosts]
      ports = [ for idx in range(length(name)):
            {
               name: name[idx]
               number: number[idx]
               protocol: protocol[idx]            
            }
      ]
    }    
}
)}


// /modules/istio/variables.tf
variable "service_entry" {
  type = map(object({
    service_entry = string
    namespace     = string
    hosts         = list(string)
    name          = list(string)
    number        = list(number)
    protocol      = list(string)
    resolution    = string
  }))
  default = {}
}


// ./modules/istio/main.tf
resource "k8s_manifest" "service-entry" {
  for_each = var.service_entry
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/manifests/serviceEntry.yaml.tpl", {
    service_entry_name = each.value.service_entry
    namespace          = each.value.namespace
    hosts              = each.value.hosts
    name               = each.value.name
    number             = each.value.number
    protocol           = each.value.protocol
    resolution         = each.value.resolution
  })
}


// ./main.tf
module "istio_service_entry_dp" {
  source = "./modules/istio"

  depends_on = [
    module.event_hub_ingress,
    module.checkpoint_storage_account,
    module.postgres_server
  ]

  providers = {
    k8s = k8s.data_plane
  }

  service_entry = {
    sa = {
      service_entry = "storage-account-spark"
      namespace     = var.datapipeline_namespace
      hosts = [data.terraform_remote_state.datahub_infrastructure.outputs.csv_fapp.fqdn,
        data.terraform_remote_state.datahub_infrastructure.outputs.dp_adl_storage_account.fqdn,
        data.terraform_remote_state.datahub_infrastructure.outputs.csv_upload_storage.fqdn,
      module.checkpoint_storage_account.dp_checkpoint_storage.fqdn]
      resolution = "DNS"
      name       = ["https"]
      number     = [443]
      protocol   = ["HTTPS"]
    },
    eventhub = {
      service_entry = "event-hub-spark"
      namespace     = var.datapipeline_namespace
      hosts         = ["${var.event_hub_ingress_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net"]
      resolution    = "DNS"
      name          = ["https", "AMQP", "AMQP-5672", "kafka"]
      number        = [443, 5671, 5672, 9093]
      protocol      = ["HTTPS", "TCP", "TCP", "TLS"]
    },
    db = {
      service_entry = "postgres-db"
      namespace     = var.datapipeline_namespace
      hosts         = [module.postgres_server.fqdn]
      resolution    = "DNS"
      name          = ["tcp"]
      number        = [5432]
      protocol      = ["TCP"]
    }
  }
}
```